# select and update based on a child objects property minimum value using Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a Type Supplier that has a property SupplierId and a another property NearestLocation which is a of Type SupplierLocation, the SupplierLocation consists of properties SupplierId and DistanceFromDevice

```
class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public SupplierLocation NearestLocation { get; set; }
}

class SupplierLocation
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public decimal DistanceFromDevice { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude {get; set;}
}
```

I have a List of all my Supplierlocations a supplier can have a n number of locations. I have also calculated the DistanceFromDevice property for each location.
I have a  List whose id's can be found in the SupplierLocations List.

What I would like to do using linq is to join my supplier to the SupplierLocation by the SupplierId and populate the NearestLocation Property of the Supplier class with the the Location that has the least DistanceFromDevice value of all the locations for that particular supplier.

Hope this makes sense. Can this be done using linq.

Many thanks in advance.
Paul

Comment: Why do you specifically do you want to use LINQ? Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, couldn't you loop through your `SupplierLocation` list, look for a matching `SupplierId` and keep track of the lowest `DistanceFromDevice`. Keep of running list `Supplier` that match the ID and the current minimum, and at the end, either use the first one (if that meets your business logic) or throw and exception if there shouldn't be more than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example in LINQPad

```
void Main()
{
    var suppliers = new List<Supplier> 
    {
        new Supplier() {SupplierId = 1},
        new Supplier() {SupplierId = 2},
        new Supplier() {SupplierId = 5}
    };      

    var locations = new List<SupplierLocation>
    {
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 1, DistanceFromDevice = 10, Latitude = 1, Longitude = 2},
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 1, DistanceFromDevice = 20, Latitude = 1, Longitude = 3},
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 1, DistanceFromDevice = 30, Latitude = 1, Longitude = 4},
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 1, DistanceFromDevice = 40, Latitude = 1, Longitude = 5},
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 2, DistanceFromDevice = 10, Latitude = 2, Longitude = 2},
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 2, DistanceFromDevice = 20, Latitude = 2, Longitude = 3},
        new SupplierLocation {SupplierId = 3, DistanceFromDevice = 10, Latitude = 3, Longitude = 2}
    };

    var result = from s in suppliers
        join l in locations on s.SupplierId equals l.SupplierId
        into grp
        where grp.Count() > 0
        select new Supplier() { SupplierId = s.SupplierId, NearestLocation = grp.OrderBy (g => g.DistanceFromDevice).First()};

    result.Dump();
}

class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public SupplierLocation NearestLocation{ get; set; }
}

class SupplierLocation
{ 
    public int SupplierId { get ;set; }
    public decimal DistanceFromDevice  { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude {get; set;}  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad this does the trick - appreciate your time. One small thing though - If I don't have any locations for one particular supplierId -I get an InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements, - I will try remove all of these Suppliers out of the Supplier List first and then do the join - I guess- unless there is a better way of handling this

Comment: @Paul, I updated my code to handle the case where you don't have any locations for one particular supplier.  Please take a look.

Comment: Many thanks this is now working perfectly with the count added

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to set `NearestLocation` on `Supplier` where the `SupplierId` is equal to one in `List<SupplierLocation>`?

Assume you have a `List<SupplierLocation>` named "Locations" and "currentSupplier" is the `Supplier` you want to assign the NearestLocation of:

```
try
{

    var minForSupplier = Locations.Where(x => x.SupplierId == currentSupplier.SupplierId).Min(x => x.DistanceFromDevice);

    currentSupplier.NearestLocation = Locations.Where(x => x.SupplierId == currentSupplier.SupplierId && x.DistanceFromDevice == minForSupplier).Single();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    // There is more than one SupplierLocation
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this too Ryan - this solution helped cater for the fact that the locations may not have existed and also the fact that I was not creating a new supplier each time - i was updating the existing supplier with the nearest location